# AndroidManifest.xml does not exist Facebook SDK for Unity

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

When I try to regenerate the Android manifest I get this error:

```
FileNotFoundException: /Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Apk/AndroidManifest.xml does not exist
System.IO.File.Copy (System.String sourceFileName, System.String destFileName, Boolean overwrite) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/File.cs:107)
System.IO.File.Copy (System.String sourceFileName, System.String destFileName) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/File.cs:86)
UnityEditor.FacebookEditor.ManifestMod.GenerateManifest () (at Assets/Facebook/Editor/android/ManifestMod.cs:67)
Facebook.Unity.Editor.FacebookSettingsEditor.AndroidUtilGUI () (at Assets/Facebook/Editor/FacebookSettingsEditor.cs:210)
Facebook.Unity.Editor.FacebookSettingsEditor.OnInspectorGUI () (at Assets/Facebook/Editor/FacebookSettingsEditor.cs:63)
UnityEditor.InspectorWindow.DrawEditor (UnityEditor.Editor editor, Int32 editorIndex, Boolean rebuildOptimizedGUIBlock, System.Boolean& showImportedObjectBarNext, UnityEngine.Rect& importedObjectBarRect) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Inspector/InspectorWindow.cs:1235)
UnityEditor.DockArea:OnGUI()
```

Obviously, if I try to build the SDK package I get an alert:

```
/Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Apk/AndroidManifest.xml does not exist
```

And this log:

```
InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object
System.Collections.Stack.Peek () (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections/Stack.cs:321)
UnityEngine.GUILayoutUtility.EndLayoutGroup () (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/IMGUI/Managed/GUILayoutUtility.cs:289)
UnityEngine.GUILayout.EndVertical () (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/IMGUI/Managed/GUILayout.cs:317)
UnityEditor.EditorGUILayout.EndVertical () (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/EditorGUI.cs:7048)
UnityEditor.InspectorWindow.DrawEditor (UnityEditor.Editor editor, Int32 editorIndex, Boolean rebuildOptimizedGUIBlock, System.Boolean& showImportedObjectBarNext, UnityEngine.Rect& importedObjectBarRect) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Inspector/InspectorWindow.cs:1245)
UnityEditor.InspectorWindow.DrawEditors (UnityEditor.Editor[] editors) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Inspector/InspectorWindow.cs:1030)
UnityEditor.InspectorWindow.OnGUI () (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Inspector/InspectorWindow.cs:352)
System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:222)
```

I have Unity 5.4.1f1 and Facebook SDK 7.8.

Comment: this is odd, why don't you manually check if the manifest is there at /Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Apk/AndroidManifest.xml ??

Comment: It was weird, I had the Android Player but no the Android manifest, I reinstall the Android module for Unity and now it is working. Thanks!